# Automatic weighing deforms my character when rigged

Tags: armature

The rigify armature was adjusted so the whole armature was inside the character mesh and when it came to weighing part it deformed any help on how to avoid this?

[image: deformed character after weighing auto]

Comment: Follow these steps:
File-User Preferences-File-Tick Auto Run Python Scripts

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should first adjust the meta-rig armature to fit your character. Then generate the rig with Rigify and finally assign weights. Bad things usually happen if you scale the rig after its been generated.